# How do I share sections from the notebook via e-mail in Microsoft OneNote for Mac?

Tags: email, onenote

I am utilizing Microsoft OneNote version 15.2.2 on a Mac.  Is it possible to share sections from the notebook via email as an attachment that can be edited, instead of only in the body of the email?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. OneNote for Mac does not support local files in any fashion, including saving them. You are expected to use OneDrive and SharePoint instead. Your best bet would be to use File | Share | Email Page | As Message and paste the body into a TextEdit Document.